# Sorting a GRanges object based on its seqnames

Tags: r

I am trying to sort a Granges object based on its seqnames.

I have a GRanges object, genome.ref, that has intervals in a random order.

```
seqnames(genome.ref)
factor-Rle of length 3141 with 5 runs
Lengths:   724   844    86   722   765
Values : CHR02 CHR04 CHR01 CHR03 CHR05
Levels(5): CHR02 CHR04 CHR01 CHR03 CHR05
```

If I use sort, R will sort based on the values, but not by alphanumerical order:

```
sort(genome.ref)
```

The resulting Granges object will have all CHR02 intervals first, then CHR04, then CHR01 etc. grouped together instead of being random, but the order will NOT be alphanumerical based on seqlevels (i.e. the CHR01 intervals will not come first).

How do I specify the order to be alphanumerical using the sort command?

Comment: You should post output of `dput(genome.ref)` and a library call of the packages expected to handle that sort of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest, when creating `genome.ref` to use the `sortSeqlevels` function within the GenomicRanges package.  This cleverly removes any 'chr' prefixes, and also deals with roman numerals and X/Y chromosomes.

Otherwise you're best creating a new annotation using `seqinfo(genome.ref, new2old=mapping) <- Seqinfo(reordered)` where you'll need to create (carefully!) the `reordered` and `mapping` variables to reflect the new order (probably using sortSeqlevels again) and the correspondence between old and new, respectively.  So as you see, much easier to start off with the right order first in your initial call to the the `GRanges` constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I have done as you suggested. In my particular case it was easier to specify the correct order in seqinfo. Is sortSeqlevels an option that you specify when you call Granges() or is it a separate function?